# 1-3-2 verb order in Nebensätze with complex tenses

Tags: grammar, verb

In [*Alices Abenteuer im Wunderland*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/19778/19778-h/19778-h.htm), for example, we find a clause like this:

> daß sie sich darüber hätte wundern sollen

If it was a main clause one would say *Sie hätte sich darüber wundern sollen.*

And later:

> Kindern, die ... sich von wilden Thieren hatten fressen lassen

with the same kind of verb order.

According to what I understood of what I was taught, when this becomes a subordinate clause, the finite verb (*hätte*, *hatten*) should move to the end of the clause. Why does it instead move to this position in the middle of the clause? What is the general rule?

Comment: It’s not wrong to put the finite verb at the very end as in *darüber wundern sollen hätte* or *die sich von wilden Tieren fressen lassen hatten.* However, in the case of the *Ersatzinfinitiv* used, the word order is often switched because the *Ersatzinfinitiv* can function as an infinitive.

Comment: @Jan: I had never heard of Ersatzinfinitiv before. That's helpful, thank you.